# Not able to access wcf restful post method in ios

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, wcf

I am using post method in `WCFrestful` services and using it from `ios` but not getting parameter value in `WCF` method.

```
[OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceData))]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "json/PassTwoParamsToCheckFault?firstparam={firstparam}")]
        String PassTwoParamsToCheckFault(string firstparam);
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the query string of a `POST` request

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(ServiceData))]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "json/PassTwoParamsToCheckFault?firstparam={firstparam}")]
String PassTwoParamsToCheckFault(string firstparam){
    if (context != null)
    {
        var result = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters["firstparam"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Where  write this in wcf service ? actually i am new to wcf services.

Comment: Modified the answer as per your request.

Comment: thanks for reply,not wotking getting "NullReferenceException" on  WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters["firstparam"];   line and what is context